# Angular Material component with bootstrap alignment issue

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-material2

I am creating a new application in angular 4.
I was confused in bootstrap and Angular material, thus I have decided to go with including both.

When I use autocomplete, input and a select inside `div` with `bootstrap` grid, the alignment is not correct which means the controls move up and down on select.

1. Is this approach correct?
2. The controls overlap when I resize the window.

   [image: Overlapping controls]
3. How do I add a bootstrap sidenav which will hide whem I click a button and adjust dynamically?
4. On mobile in portrait mode, it should display as grids but it doesn't show as grids.
5. When I resize the window, the components fill the entire `div` and show as blank space.

Here is the code I used.

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Maintain Equipment </h1>
    </div>
    <form class="example-form">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">Add Equipment</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                        <md-input-container>
                            <input mdInput placeholder="Manufacture" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
                        </md-input-container>

                        <md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
                            <md-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state">
                                {{ state }}
                            </md-option>
                        </md-autocomplete>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                        <md-input-container>
                            <input mdInput placeholder="Model" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
                        </md-input-container>

                        <md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
                            <md-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state">
                                {{ state }}
                            </md-option>
                        </md-autocomplete>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                        <md-input-container>
                            <input mdInput placeholder="Type" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
                        </md-input-container>

                        <md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
                            <md-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state">
                                {{ state }}
                            </md-option>
                        </md-autocomplete>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                        <md-input-container>
                            <input mdInput placeholder="Brand" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
                        </md-input-container>

                        <md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
                            <md-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state">
                                {{ state }}
                            </md-option>
                        </md-autocomplete>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                        <md-select placeholder="Frequency start">
                            <md-option *ngFor="let FrequencyStartEndRange of FrequencyStartEndRanges" [value]="FrequencyStartEndRange.value">
                                {{ FrequencyStartEndRange.viewValue }}
                            </md-option>
                        </md-select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                        <md-select placeholder="Frequency End">
                            <md-option *ngFor="let FrequencyStartEndRange of FrequencyStartEndRanges" [value]="FrequencyStartEndRange.value">
                                {{ FrequencyStartEndRange.viewValue }}
                            </md-option>
                        </md-select>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                        <md-input-container>
                            <input mdInput placeholder="Unid ID" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
                        </md-input-container>

                        <md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
                            <md-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state">
                                {{ state }}
                            </md-option>
                        </md-autocomplete>
                    </div>

                     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                        <md-input-container>
                            <input mdInput placeholder="Serial" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
                        </md-input-container>

                        <md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
                            <md-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state">
                                {{ state }}
                            </md-option>
                        </md-autocomplete>
                    </div>

                     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                        <md-input-container>
                            <input mdInput placeholder="Asset Tag" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
                        </md-input-container>

                        <md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
                            <md-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state">
                                {{ state }}
                            </md-option>
                        </md-autocomplete>
                    </div>

                     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                        <md-input-container>
                            <input mdInput placeholder="Description" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
                        </md-input-container>

                        <md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
                            <md-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state">
                                {{ state }}
                            </md-option>
                        </md-autocomplete>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<hr>
<md-card>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                        <md-input-container>
                            <input mdInput placeholder="Manufacture" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
                        </md-input-container>

                        <md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
                            <md-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state">
                                {{ state }}
                            </md-option>
                        </md-autocomplete>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                        <md-input-container>
                            <input mdInput placeholder="Model" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
                        </md-input-container>

                        <md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
                            <md-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state">
                                {{ state }}
                            </md-option>
                        </md-autocomplete>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                        <md-input-container>
                            <input mdInput placeholder="Type" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
                        </md-input-container>

                        <md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
                            <md-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state">
                                {{ state }}
                            </md-option>
                        </md-autocomplete>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                        <md-input-container>
                            <input mdInput placeholder="Brand" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
                        </md-input-container>

                        <md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
                            <md-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state">
                                {{ state }}
                            </md-option>
                        </md-autocomplete>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                        <md-select placeholder="Frequency start">
                            <md-option *ngFor="let FrequencyStartEndRange of FrequencyStartEndRanges" [value]="FrequencyStartEndRange.value">
                                {{ FrequencyStartEndRange.viewValue }}
                            </md-option>
                        </md-select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                        <md-select placeholder="Frequency End">
                            <md-option *ngFor="let FrequencyStartEndRange of FrequencyStartEndRanges" [value]="FrequencyStartEndRange.value">
                                {{ FrequencyStartEndRange.viewValue }}
                            </md-option>
                        </md-select>
                    </div>
                </div>
       </md-card>
    </form>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; Copyright 2013 Tutorial Republic</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's better to use either bootstrap or Angular Material.

Comment: but how to apply layout as i am designing responsive website

Comment: For responsive design, use [angular flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) instead of bootstrap with angular material.

Comment: @user1999324 Try not to have many questions in your question. Also, I don't understand what you mean by "sanp".